# Is this a correct use of the prototype design pattern in Swift?

Tags: design-patterns, swift

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        let cellPrototype: NDCustomTableViewCell = NDCustomTableViewCell()
    return cellPrototype.frame.size.height;
}
```

**let cellPrototype** being a constant, will this execute only one? Not the function heightForRow, but the initialisation of the cell prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate a new cell every time the function is called. Over its scope (two lines), `cellPrototype` will not be allowed to change (though the cell itself can be changed).

The method you want is `dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier()`. Correct cell configuration is a slightly involved topic, so you should read the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) for full details.

---

EDIT: Thinking about this a little more, another way to handle this (rather than `dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier`) is to just create an property that holds a prototypical cell for querying.

Comment: Oh the things we don't think about! Thank you :)